# travis running my tests against different versions of ember

Tags: ember.js, travis-ci

I have this [repo](https://github.com/dagda1/ember-autosuggest) which uses `ember 1.11.0`.

My bower.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "emberx-autosuggest",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.11.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
    "ember-qunit": "0.3.1",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.15",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1"
  }
}
```

My tests all pass locally but when I push to github, travis appears to be running my tests against ember 1.10.0, 1.11.0 and 1.12.0-beta.1.

I only want to run against 1.11.0, how can I configure travis to do this?

My travis.yml looks like this:

```
---
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.12"

sudo: false

cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules

before_install:
  - "npm config set spin false"
  - "npm install -g npm@^2"

install:
  - npm install -g bower
  - npm install
  - bower install

script:
  - npm test
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "emberx-autosuggest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Tag picker functionality",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember try:testall"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/dagda1/emberx-autosuggest.git",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.3",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.8",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.10",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-disable-prototype-extensions": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-try": "0.0.4"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ember-addon"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.4",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "ember-addon": {
    "configPath": "tests/dummy/config"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json? Do you have ember-try installed?

Comment: I've posted my package.json.  ember-try is now in the package.json by default.  I take it that is what is doing this?

Comment: OK, I see what is happening, thanks for pointing this out.  I had no idea it was ember-try doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall ember-try, or edit config/ember-try.js to test only the versions of ember you would like.